# Storing a DNS name as compactly as possible in memory (preferably in C#)

Tags: string, compression, c#

What is the most compact way to encode/save DNS names in memory?

For example, storing "www.google.com" as a string in .NET will result in the object being encoded as UTF-16, and it will consume twice as much memory as plain ASCII... but for the purpose of storing DNS names, ASCII is overkill.

The only characters that are needed are:

- A..Z  (case insensitive)
- 0..9
- Hyphen
- underscore
- period
- Asterisk (not legal DNS, but used in ACLs such as *.google.com) always as a leading character, never elsewhere.

A total of 40 characters.. which fits within single byte with plenty room to spare.

My code golf question/challenge is what is the most compact way to store a string of characters in memory and maximizing in memory storage?

The inspiration for this challenge [came from this blog entry.](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings.aspx)

Comment: How do you win the competition?

Comment: You meant UTF-16 for the .NET framework. In UTF-8, this name would take up just as much as ASCII.

Comment: Try http://cs.stackexchange.com/ - there's probably already a question about basic information theory which would tell you all you need to know.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity?

Comment: Actually, underscores are not allowed in DNS names. [RFC 3696](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3696#section-2)

Comment: As stated this looks like a question for Stack Overflow (that is, it is a question). CodeGolf.SE is a plce for playing certain programming *games*. It would be essentially trivial to turn this into a [code-golf]---you just add the tag (and probably the one @beary suggests as well) and resign yourself to getting answer many languages. But I am closing until that is done just to encourage you to read the FAQ before posting to a new Stack Exchange site. Flag when you are ready for this to be re-opened.

Answer (score 3):

You could interpret it as a base 39 number. Since only the first character can be an asterisk, you can encode it as the sign. If i use the characters as digits in the order you named them, `www.google.com` would be `10903065870001232914011` in decimal and `24f0e6f41d8ecd3a65b` in hex, which could be stored in 10 bytes.

`*.google.com` would be `-310664672884413873` in decimal and `fbb04c2040762a4f` in hex, if you store it in 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, that's easy. You just zip it.

Comment: `gzip` on a file containing `www.google.com` gives 42 bytes.

Comment: Ah... when you use Windows' built in zipping routines, you get a 132 byte file. Oh well.